# SQL Unmatched Delete

Tags: php, sql, database

Say I have two tables, `records` and `recordsclean`. Now both of these tables have 15 columns of information. I want to compare them using just one unique column and identify the unmatched results. Once I find those unmatched results I want to remove them from one table.

```
SELECT  email
FROM    records
WHERE   id NOT IN      
(        
       SELECT  email    
       FROM    recordsclean      
);
```

Now I'm using `email` in this instance but likely I'm going to use something more unique like registration numbers. I'm just testing it with email addresses. So this produces a list of emails found in `records` that are not found in `recordsclean`. The table `records` is going to hold historical data that I plan to keep indefinitely where as `recordsclean` is going to be a fresh set of information. I want to compare the full version of `records` to the new `recordsclean` and then identify / remove anything that matches from `recordsclean`.

1. Data is added to `records`.
2. New data is added to `recordsclean`.
3. SQL command runs and identifies matching records in both.
4. SQL command runs and removes any matching records from `recordsclean` only.

Comment: Why are you comparing `id` to `email` from the other table? Shouldn't it be `WHERE email NOT IN`?

Comment: What's your question? You have lots of "I want X" statements, but nowhere have you said what problem you're having.

Comment: Are you asking how you can compare more than one column at a time, not just `email`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare multiple columns and find all the rows that don't match, use a `LEFT JOIN` pattern rather than `NOT IN`.

```
SELECT rc.*
FROM recordsclean AS rc
LEFT JOIN records AS r
    ON rc.col1 = r.col1 AND rc.col2 = r.col2 AND rc.col3 = r.col3 ...
WHERE r.id IS NULL
```

To delete them, just change it to a `DELETE` query.

```
DELETE rc
FROM recordsclean AS rc
LEFT JOIN records AS r
    ON rc.col1 = r.col1 AND rc.col2 = r.col2 AND rc.col3 = r.col3 ...
WHERE r.id IS NULL
```